# When I use CListView widget in YII the fontsize of my whole website changes. (I use flowtype for fontscaling)

Tags: php, css, yii

When I use my CListView Widget in a page the fontsize of my whole website changes. I use flowtype to scale my fonts and keep everything responsive. Only when I use this widget everything changes, nog only the data of the widget itself.

I tried to turn the css styling of the widget of and tried to control it via an own css file, but this doesn't matter.

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
    'cssFile'=>false,
)); ?>
```

The content of the view I'm calling doesn't matter either. Only when I remove the widget and put some text instead it changes back to normal.

Does someone have any idea what's happening here?

Comment: Found out it changes only the fonts with an "em" size, but the problem remains since I use em for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from [official documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView#cssFile-detail) for ClistView

> cssFile property
>
> public string $cssFile;
>
> the URL of the CSS file used by this list view. Defaults to null,
>   meaning using the integrated CSS file. If this is set false, you are
>   responsible to explicitly include the necessary CSS file in your page.

Follow it, when you used CListView, default css `.../listview/style.css` file would be imported into your page, it could change your current layout if some of css is coincided with each other.

You can override it

```
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
     'cssFile' => 'your-css-file-path.css',
      ...
      )
```

Comment: Yes, I can and tried it allready. However, I can kind of get the font of the rest of the website back to it's normal size by setting: body{font-size:146%;} in my listview css. But this is quite a dirty solution. Does anyone know why and/or where these values are being changed?

Comment: But then my flowtype scaling doesn't work anymore. But when I remove my flowtype instances I keep having the same problem...

Comment: CGridView does the same thing and with cssFile set to false it changes the CListView, but the rest of the page is still smaller. So there is something else that affects the page but still can't figger out what..

Answer (score 0):

So, eventually tried to copy the parsed code from the page source into my view. So in pagecode this was exactly the same output as the widget does in the page. Now I didn't had the resizing problem. So the widgets do something more then I can see.

For the solution I wrote an own widget to get my data in which I can control everything that happens. So no problem left anymore. Thanks for your help Telvin!